# I cannot change sql server's default port (1433)

Tags: sql-server, tcp, port

I want to add another port to default 1433 port of sql server. So I opened the configuration manager, selected `Protocols for MSSQLSERVER` and then double clicked on `TCP/IP` to see its properties. Then I selected the `IP Addresses` tab and scrolled down right to the `IPAll` section. and then I change 1433 to 1433,1450 so that I could also connect to the server using 1450 port. The problem is this change requires to restart sql server service and I cannot start the server after stopping it because of the following error:

```
The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.
```

I see the following error in event log:

```
SQL Server could not spawn FRunCM thread.
```

If I remove 1450 from tcp ports, sql server will be able to run again without any problem.

I have done this before but I don't understand why I cannot do it on this server.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you set the second port to 5000?

Comment: No it didn't work again. I think it could be an anti virus running on the server blocking the port. I have to check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new TDS endpoint in the server first, see [How to: Configure the Database Engine to Listen on Multiple TCP Ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189310.aspx):

```
CREATE ENDPOINT [CustomConnection]
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP
   (LISTENER_PORT = 1450, LISTENER_IP =ALL)
FOR TSQL() ;
GO
```

then configure the engine to listen on both ports, as you're doing. Make sure you choose a free port and make sure the port is allowed in Firewall.

The usual reason to add multiple listening ports is to affinitize clients to NUMA or soft-NUMA, see [How to: Map TCP/IP Ports to NUMA Nodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345346.aspx) and [How to: Configure SQL Server to Use Soft-NUMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345357.aspx).

Comment: doesn't seem to work for sql server community (2017)