# How to change SQL servers default port

Tags: sql-server, port

Can you please let me know that how can we change the default port of SQL Server.

Thank you,

Comment: See here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167343/i-cannot-change-sql-servers-default-port-1433

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54387592/109941

Answer (score 0):

If a default instance of SQL Server is listening on a port other than port 1433, you must either define a server alias name or change the global default port by using the Client Network Utility. However, you can also make the default instance of SQL Server listen on multiple static ports. For more info, see [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/823938).

Comment: no problem. if this answers your question, then please click on the checkmark next to the answer.