# Change SQL Server default TCP port

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, registry

I want to change the SQL Server default TCP port in server. I know the default port is 1433, and I know how do this with UI, but I need a code such as registry or batch file or programming language like Delphi, VB, C#

Thank you

Comment: I found this and I put this in a file with .reg extention

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\BMODIRAN\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp]
"TcpHideFlag"=dword:00000000
"TcpPort"="14340"
"TcpDynamicPorts"=""

`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I have in a Powershell script that's part of my server build from a couple of jobs ago:

```
param (
    [string]$server_name = $(Read-Host -prompt Server)
)
$Machine = new-object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' $server_name

$instance = $Machine.ServerInstances[ 'MSSQLSERVER' ];

$instance.ServerProtocols[ 'Tcp' ].IsEnabled = $true;
$instance.ServerProtocols[ 'Tcp' ].Alter();

$ipAll = $instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].IPAddresses['IPAll'];
$ipAll.IPAddressProperties['TcpPort'].Value = "14330";
$ipAll.IPAddressProperties['TcpDynamicPorts'].Value = ""
$instance.ServerProtocols['Tcp'].Alter();
```

It assumes a non-named instance of SQL Server and that the port you want to set is `14330`. Adjust to meet your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an excerpt from the [dockerfile](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/blob/master/windows/mssql-server-windows/dockerfile) used to build the official Microsoft SQL Server 2017 image for Windows.

```
RUN stop-service MSSQLSERVER ; \
    set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql14.MSSQLSERVER\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpdynamicports -value '' ; \
    set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql14.MSSQLSERVER\mssqlserver\supersocketnetlib\tcp\ipall' -name tcpport -value 1433 ; \
    set-itemproperty -path 'HKLM:\software\microsoft\microsoft sql server\mssql14.MSSQLSERVER\mssqlserver\' -name LoginMode -value 2 ;
```

The `Set-ItemProperty` PowerShell commands configure the SQL Server ports and set the login mode to allow both SQL Server and Windows authentication. These same commands can be run against a local SQL instance after changing the registry paths as appropriate for your version and installation as well as the desired port number. The instance needs to be restarted for the changes to become effective.